# Is it possible to tranfer changed files to another working folder in Subversion

Tags: svn

I have question: If I have a working folder that points to the head revision. If I have made some changes to the working folder, what is the easiest way to move those changes to another working folder that points to the same revision number. 
That is to say, how can I create an exact copy of the working folder including the changes I have made?

At some point in time I used a version control system that could do what I want by taking a copy of the changes, place them in a cmd file, which I were to execute on the other working folder. This it called a "changelist" which is not the same as a SVN changelist.

Thank you for your help
Jeeji

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `svn diff` and pipe the result to a file. Then you can go to your new WC and do a `patch` command to re-apply them (then use `svn commit` to commit them)

This will only work with files; things like renaming of files or deletion of directories will not be represented in such a file.

On Windows you can use TortoiseSVN which has graphical tools to do this sort of thing for you; on the command-line take a look at the man pages for the commands above.

Answer (score 1):

Create a patch file with `svn diff`

```
svn diff > ~/changes.diff
```

and apply the patch to another working copy

```
patch -p0 -i ~/changes.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would certainly be to just ***copy the whole working copy at the file system level***, creating a new working copy.

But I think `svn copy path/to/old/wc path/to/new/wc` should work, too (also creating a new working copy).

I haven't tested the latter, though, so you should first try it with a dummy copy of your working copy.

Comment: I thought about taking a copy of the working copy. But doesn't the working copy contain information specific to the location of the working copy? If not, then I guess it would be possible. Do you have experience in copying the working copy over to another location? Jeeji

Comment: I want to add that I need the copy to work on another machine also. So if the  ".svn" contains information about the machine too, then it will not work. I guess there is no reason it should do that, but who knows. Please let me know what you know about the matter

Comment: @Jihad: No, the working copy does not contain information about the path (or machine). In fact, I have been making copies of working copies quite often, and never ran into any problems. I often do this when I need to interrupt work on something (e.g., a feature) to work on something else (usually a bugfix). I make a copy of the work begun (on the feature), revert all the changes in the working copy I made the copy from, and start work there from a clean slate. Later I go back to the copy I made and continue (with the feature) where I left.

Comment: @Jihad: sbi is right. I do copy working copies frequently. One common case is when you hava a slow connection to the repository and need to work in a different branch. Instead of checking out the whole branch, you copy an existing working copy in your machine and then svn switch to the branch you want to work (doing a svn revert previously to clean your working copy)